# How to restore a large DB back up with PhpMyAdmin on Mac

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am running locally PHPMyAdmin on my Mac. Because it is locally, I am not concerned about security, as the site I am working will never be put on the internet and can only be accessed from my machine.

I am trying to restore a large database file that is 193MB. I get the following error message:

```
Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume.

INSERT INTO `cache_form` (`cid`, `data`, `expire`, `created`, `serialized`) VALUES
('form_form-75Jpz4IPsKk4FR7zNNI5DC-wvzB2k0iIorcpikuKU5Y', 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[...]
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
```

How can I fix it?

Steps I have tried

**1. Create an upload directory**
I have created an upload directory and so can now select the back up from the PhpmyAdmin interface. The same error occurs.

**2. Zipping the backup**
I have tried different forms of compression, including Zip and GZ. Same error each time.

**3. Reuploading the file**
The error message says if I resubmit, it will continue. But it does not.

**4. Creating a PHP.ini file**

```
I have created a php.ini file with the following values:
php_value upload_max_filesize 10000M
php_value post_max_size 10000M
php_value max_execution_time 9999999999
php_value max_input_time 99999999999
```

I know its been picked up by the server, because the file size limit in the interface has increase. But the upload still fails.

**5. Editing config.inc.php**
I have added the following line to my config.inc.php file:

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 999999999999;
```

Same error still occurs.

**6. Using Big Dump**
With Big Dump I get the following error message:

*Error at the line 364: ('form_state_form-75Jpz4IPsKk4FR7zNNI5DC-wvzB2k0iIorcpikuKU5Y', 0x613a363a7b733a31303a226275696c645f696e666f223b613a343a7b733a343a2261726773223b613a323a7b693a303b4f3a343a22766965 [There are 1000s of these numbers, it goes on for many screens].
MySQL: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
Stopped on error*

Answer (score 2):

I would personally not bother restoring such a large file with phpmyadmin and instead use the MySQL command line tool. Run `mysql -h localhost -u <user> -p < dumpfile`.

Make sure that the dump file is uncompressed and a readable series of mysql statements

Details for how to use the MySQL command line tool can be found at [4.2.2 Connecting to the MySQL Server](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php) of the MySQL 5.0 reference

Comment: Thanks for your help! when I run that command it just displays the MSQL help screen. It doesn't seem to do anything else.